# Reference token value at parse time

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying to parse the following:

```
<delimiter><text><delimiter><text><delimter>
```

Where `delimiter` can be any single literal character that is repeated three times and `text` can be any printable characters beside the delimiter character *(the first and second occurence of `text` do **not** have to match and can be blank)*.

This is what I have come up with however `text` consumes from the first delimiter to the end of the string.

```
from pyparsing import Word, printables

delimiter = Word(printables, exact=1)
text = (Word(printables) + ~delimiter)

parser = delimiter + text  # + delimiter + text + delimiter

tests = [
    ('_abc_123_', ['_', 'abc', '_', '123', '_']),
    ('-abc-123-', ['-', 'abc', '-', '123', '-']),
    ('___', ['_', '', '_', '', '_']),
]

for test, expected in tests:
    print parser.parseString(test), '<=>', expected
```

Script output:

```
['_', 'abc_123_'] <=> ['_', 'abc', '_', '123', '_']
['-', 'abc-123-'] <=> ['-', 'abc', '-', '123', '-']
['_', '__'] <=> ['_', '', '_', '', '_']
```

I think I need to make use of `Future` but I can get my head around excluding the value of the delimiter at parse time from text token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition was correct, you need to use a `Forward` (not `Future`) to capture the definition of text, since this is not fully knowable until parse time. Also, your use of Word has to exclude the delimiter character using the `excludeChars` argument - just using `Word(printables) + ~delimiter` is not sufficient.

Here is your code, marked up with the necessary changes, and hopefully some helpful comments:

```
delimiter = Word(printables, exact=1)
text = Forward() #(Word(printables) + ~delimiter)
def setTextExcludingDelimiter(s,l,t):
    # define Word as all printable characters, excluding the delimiter character
    # the excludeChars argument for Word is how this is done
    text_word = Word(printables, excludeChars=t[0]).setName("text")
    # use '<<' operator to assign the text_word definition to the 
    # previously defined text expression
    text << text_word
# attach parse action to delimiter, so that once it is matched, 
# it will define the correct expression for text
delimiter.setParseAction(setTextExcludingDelimiter)

# make the text expressions Optional with default value of '' to satisfy 3rd test case
parser = delimiter + Optional(text,'') + delimiter + Optional(text,'') + delimiter
```